# "Enable the Visual Studio hosting" process compile option for Release configs

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, .net-2.0

It appears to me as though the "Enable the Visual Studio hosting process" option on the Project Properties => debug tab is checked by default for both Debug and Release Configurations. If this item is checked, it seems that this results in the creation of a appname.VSHost.exe executable and associated configuration file that is used when running in the Visual Studio environment.

If this is the case, is there a reason why this option is set by default for Release Configurations since it seems this file would not be needed for a prod release? Is there any benefit to keeping it? I am tempted to remove it but the previous release included it and I hate to fix what ain't broken.

Also, I noticed that in both the Debug and Release folders that two new files that were not in the last release were created: AppName.application and appName.exe.Manifest. The previous release was compiled with VS2010 as was this and the .NET Framework is unchanged at 2.0. What might be responsible for these 2 fiels now appearing in both folders? Also, what differences would you normally expect to see between WinForms Release and Debug folders? I like having as much opportunity for debug info in errors messages as possible and I thought that dbg files were related to that. I assume that the compile optin "Generate Debug Info" is responsible for that at the expense of making your app clightly more transparent to hackers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the hosting process (both in debug and release builds).  It is only there to improve the debugging experience.  Note that there are times when you do want/need to debug a release build, and the hosting process makes this potentially more functional.

For details on what it adds, see the [Hosting Process page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185331.aspx).

That being said, you wouldn't deploy the `*.vshost.exe` files with your application.  Having VS create them does not detract in any way, so it's typically harmless to leave these in place.

Comment: I find the hand around in memory far too often, after a debug session unnaturally stops, keeping files locked, and preventing a proper 'Clean' before a rebuild.